# How to read/restore big data file (SEGY format) with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, bigdata, store

I am working on a project which needs to deal with large seismic data of SEGY format (from several GB to TB). This data represents the 3D underground structure.

Data structure is like:

```
1st tract, 2,3,5,3,5,....,6
2nd tract, 5,6,5,3,2,....,3
3rd tract, 7,4,5,3,1,....,8
...
```

What I want to ask is, in order to read and deal with the data fast, do I have to convert the data into another form? Or it's better to read from the original SEGY file? And is there any existing **C** package to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing of data of that size, you may not want to convert it into another form unless you have to - though some software does [do just that](http://www.cwp.mines.edu/sututor/node24.html). I found a [list of free geophysics software on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_geophysics_software) that look promising; many are open source and read/write SEGY files.

Since you are a newbie to programming, you may want to consider if the Python library [segpy](https://github.com/rob-smallshire/segpy) suits your needs rather than a C/C++ option.

Answer (score 3):

- If you need to access it **multiple** times and
- if you need to access it **randomly** and
- if you need to access it **fast**

then load it to a database **once**.

Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Notice the OP told he has large data files that don't fit in RAM for today's standards.  I work in the petroleum industry developing software solutions dealing with large data sets.  I have Seg-Ys in the hundreds of GB range and it is simply impossible to load them at once to RAM in most modern workstations.  You could improve your answer by proposing strategies to deal with such large data sets such as cubes with different levels of detail, octree indexing and caching.

Comment: @PauloCarvalho: "*... cubes with different levels of detail, octree indexing and caching*" The right databases know how to do all this. This question is tagged (**low-level**) C. The OP definitely does not want to code all this what you (rightly!) propose from scratch.

Comment: No database in the market (either commercial ou opensource solutions) handles Seg-Y format internally.  You can, at most, add tem as BLOBs for bookkeeping or, at most, add its bounding cube if a GIS extension is installed for spatial searches, but this is as far as database software can go.  Efficiently handling Seg-Y format (actually a meta-format) requires knowledge of the said format.  Often geoscience software do a pre-processing to build auxiliary files to support the mentioned strategies.  This is of course not implemented in products like MySQL, Oracle, Postgre, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Several GB is rathe medium, if we are toking about poststack.
You may use segy and convert on the fly, you may invent your own format. It depends whot you needed to do. Without changing segy format it's enough to createing indexes to traces. If segy is saved as inlines - it's faster access throug inlines, although crossline access is not very bad. 
If it is 3d seismic, the best way to have the same quick access to all inlines/crosslines is to have own format - based od beans, e.g 8x8 traces - loading all beans and selecting tarces access time may be very quick - 2-3 secends. Or you may use SSD disk, or 2,5x RAM as your SEGY.
To quickly access timeslices you have 2 ways - 3D beans or second file stored as timeslices (the quickes way). I did same kind of that 10 years ago - access time to 12 GB SEGY was acceptable - 2-3 seconds in all 3 directions.
SEGY in database? Wow ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends upon the type of data you need to extract from the SEG-Y file.

If you need to extract only the headers (Text header, Binary header, Extended Textual File headers and Trace headers) then they can be easily extracted from the SEG-Y file by opening the file as binary and extracting relevant information from the respective locations as mentioned in the data exchange formats ([rev2](http://seg.org/Portals/0/SEG/News%20and%20Resources/Technical%20Standards/seg_y_rev2_0-mar2017.pdf)). The extraction might depend upon the type of data (Post-stack or Pre-stack). Also some headers might require conversions from one format to another (e.g Text Headers are mostly encoded in EBCDIC format). The complete details about the byte locations and encoding formats can be read from the above documentation

The extraction of trace data is a bit tricky and depends upon various factors like the encoding, whether the no. of trace samples is mentioned in the trace headers, etc. A careful reading of the documentation and getting to know about the type of SEG data you are working on will surely make this task a lot easier.

Since you are working with the extracted data, I would recommend to use already existing libraries (segpy: one of the best python library I came across). There are also numerous free available SEG-Y readers, a very nice list has already been mentioned by Daniel Waechter; you can choose any one of them that suits your requirements and the type file format supported.

I recently tried to do something same using C++ (Although it has only been tested on post-stack data). The project can be found [here](https://github.com/kambojankush/Seismic-File-X-ray).